# Perl 5 - evaluating OO code in a string

Tags: perl

I have code which is basically:

```
$object = Class->new();
$message = 'get_value':
```

I want to run `$object->$message();`  But I can't get that to compile, so I'm trying

```
my $value = eval '$object->$message()';
```

But that always returns undef.

I suspect my approach is wrong - how do I run this sort of string at runtime?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Why are you trying to dynamic name a sub? A more common approach would be `$object -> get_value($some_attribute_name)` or something similar. This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: That should work. You're not showing your real code.

Comment: Well spotted. I went off looking for the problem, before I realised there wasn't one.

Comment: Yes, this is a slimmed down example to get at the real point.  I know the way stackoverflow works, if you show your entire code you get asked to slim down to a small example, so I've done that.

Comment: Yeah, but you've fallen into the classic trap - that the code you've given _doesn't show the problem_. It's why [mcve] is the route to go - put together a runnable example that exhibits the behaviour. Yours doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

A more conventional approach would be to e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

package MyObject;

sub new {
   my ( $class, %args ) = @_; 
   my $self = {}; 
   $self->{args} = \%args; 
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}

sub get_value {
   my ( $self, $attribute ) = @_; 
   return $self -> {args} -> {$attribute}; 
}

package main;

my $object = 'MyObject'->new( test => 'frobnicated', foo=>'bar'); 
print $object -> get_value('test');
```

And handle the dynamic bit in the method itself, for example.

However, if you do want to 'find' a subroutine you can use the `can` method to get the coderef:

```
my $methodname = 'get_value';
if ( my $coderef =  $object -> can($methodname) ) {
    print $coderef -> ($object,'foo');
}
```

I'm not sure this'd be generally a good thing to be doing though, as it could get quite messy. I think this approach is less likely to randomly break than eval though.

However your original approach *does* work:

```
my $value = eval '$object->$methodname("foo")';
print $value,"\n";
```

I think it might be that your sub is erroring - have you tried checking `$@` which is the return code from `eval`?

Comment: `my $value = eval '$object->$methodname("foo")';

print $value,"\n";`

Gives me syntax error near $self

`sub get {
 my $self = shift;
 my %args = (ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH') ? %{$_[0]} : @_;

 return unless($args{'object'} && $args{'message'});

 my $o = $args{'object'};
 my $m = $args{'message'}
 my $rc = eval '$o->$m()';

 die $@ if $@;

        return $rc;
}`

Comment: @NigelHorne: Please don't put code in comments. It's almost impossible to understand. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40590650/edit) to add it there.

Comment: @NigelHorne: You have a missing semicolon in `my $m = $args{'message'} my $rc = eval '$o->$m()'`

Answer (score 1):

Your initial version should work fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Class;

sub new {
  return bless { value => $_[1] }, $_[0];
}

sub get_value {
  return $_[0]->{value};
}

package main;

my $obj = Class->new('some value');
my $message = 'get_value';

print $obj->$message();
```

This works exactly as expected and prints "some value". There is no need to use `eval`.

From [perldoc perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html):

> **Method Names as Strings**
>
> Perl lets you use a scalar variable containing a string as a method
>   name:
>
> ```
> my $file = File->new( $path, $data );
>
> my $method = 'save';
> $file->$method();
> ```
>
> This works exactly like calling `$file->save()`. This can be very useful for writing dynamic code. For example, it allows you to pass a method name to be called as a parameter to another method.

So the problem is elsewhere in your code.